# How do I get the client IP and Port from it's NAT via HTTP?

Tags: php, p2p, nat, upnp

I want to make an application to send email and messages directly to other clients as a `P2P` service, using a web server to maintain a list of clients online with registration of the `IP` and `Port` sent by the `NAT` in which the client will read the list to connect directly to destiny client.

Is it possible to receive this information in an `HTTP` Web Server? How do I do it? Or may I use only an `UDP` server (`UDP Hole Punch`)?

*Something like primordial Skype, but with web server.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

From the "outside" NAT acts as your only client and you only know its (NAT's) source IP and (not always) source port.

Comment: But what if the destination wants to respond to the sender? Should it not knows the sender's port so the NAT may send the answer to the correct local computer?

Comment: @EASI: if you're using tcp/ip - you can send respond using the established connection. So you're responding to NAT and then NAT forwards the packet to the original client using its own mapping table.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get those two information? I would like to test that possibility before turn to a custom server. For IP it is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] `, but what about the port?

Comment: @EASI: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`. Not sure how it will be helpful for you though